# Creating links to things other than url's and other pdf files

Tags: cross-referencing, links, preamble

I found [this](https://castel.dev/post/research-workflow/) blog post where he talks about how he manages to do his research Ph.D. thesis and maintain his Ph.D. thesis notes.

When I create a reference link to a `note.xoj` file and I click the link, it opens another Zathura page saying it doesn't know how to open other files.

How do I make latex open a link in a certain program, I guess is what I'm asking?

Comment: you create a launch link (typically by using `\href{run:...}`) and then it is up to your pdf viewer/operating system if they can handle it or not. And the blog got it imho wrong: pdf files should normally not use the launch action but GoToR as pdfviewer don't need to launch another application to open them, they can do it themselves.

Comment: So, how would I use the `href` command to open the file in xournal? I know I'm supposed to create the file to run, but how am I going to know what file to run?

Comment: can you open the file by doubleclicking on it?

Comment: When I doubleclick it, it opens another zathura (which is my pdf viewer) instance that's blank and it says: No Name when it's supposed to open the note.xoj in xournal.

Comment: so your problem is not related to tex or latex but to your operating system.  Find out what you have to do change the default app for your file type.

Comment: The idea of `\href{run:note.xoj}{link text}` is that you don't specify which program to run, but that your operating system launches the default application for the given file type. This is different from `\href{note.xoj}{text}` because then the pdf viewer has to decide what to do. I'm not sure how Zathura implements `run:` but you can give it a try.

Comment: When I do that, I just keep having the file downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no desktop environment is detected, MIME type detection falls back to using file which—ironically—does not implement the XDG standard. If you want xdg-utils to work properly without a desktop environment, you will need to install #perl-file-mimeinfo or another xdg-open alternative.

This is what the arch wiki says. If you're running a WM (window manager) instead of a desktop environment, you're bound to have these issues arise eventually. That's exactly my case. I'm using DWM (Dynamic Window Manager). I just installed the package `perl-file-mimeinfo` and it fixed my problem

The reason this problem rises is because the window manager doesn't know what to open what application with what because it doesn't have access to the mime information. When you install this package, you give it access to the mime information, which, hence, gets you your correct application to be run.